# How to set "Configuring grub-pc" prompt for unattended/non-interactive Ubuntu 18.04 OS-Install

Tags: 18.04

I am creating a non-interactive/unattended ubuntu-18.04 os-install, and the below "Configuring grub-pc" prompt keeps coming up. The question I have is, how do you or what is the process to put this question/prompt in unattended/non-interactive os-install? I would really appreciate any ideas on this...Thanks

This is the info from the prompt.

[A new version (/tmp/grub.jW3vhy5hUB) of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.

What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub?

- install the package maintainer's version
- keep the local version currently installed
- show the differences between the versions
- show a side-by-side difference between the versions
- start a new shell to examine the situation][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoQXu.png)

Comment: Show the differences between versions first